# Shopify / Liquid - nested collection shown in URL - collection within a collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, liquid

I would like to add nested collections on my Shopify (collections within collections). For instance, the end goal is to have a website URL that reads e.g.

**www.mywebsite.com/collections/shoes/mens**

meaning you can also go on

**www.mywebsite.com/collections/shoes** to see both mens and womens.

Please do not provide answers just involving tags - I want the nested collections to show as in the URL examples above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that, this URL is preserved for collection tags.